# InCorrect Path for Rest client in Haxe

Tags: haxe, haxelib

I am a newbie to Haxe. I created the below code:

```
import restclient.RestClient;
/**
 * ...
 * @author Sriram
 */
class HaxeTest 
{
    static public function main() {
        trace("Hello, world!");
        var result = RestClient.get(
            "SOME_REST_GET_API");
        trace(result);
    }
    
}
```

I wanted to run the below command:

```
haxe --js main-javascript.js --main HaxeTest
```

But I get the below error:

```
HaxeTest.hx:1: characters 8-29 : Type not found : restclient.RestClient
HaxeTest.hx:10: characters 22-32 : Type not found : RestClient
```

I have installed the rest-client using haxelib install rest-client

Kindly assist.

Comment: You forgot to include the library during the compilation (`--library rest-client`).

Comment: Thanks Gama. My bad I forgot the --library option. I have a doubt, if I have more than one library, do I need to provide them as comma-separated (ex: rest-client, http-client etc). Is there any wild card characters like * or any xmls to add libraries while executing?

Comment: No, you need a separate `--library` per library. Maybe you are looking for HXML files. https://haxe.org/manual/compiler-usage-hxml.html

Comment: Got it. Thanks Gama11

Answer (score 1):

Installing a library doesn't directly mean it's used in compilation of the project.
You should add `-lib rest-client` to actually tell the compiler that you want to use this library

```
haxe --js main-javascript.js --main HaxeTest -lib rest-client
```

Comment: Got it.. Thanks Mark Knol